# HTTP Basic Auth protected url in new window

Tags: internet-explorer, web-applications, basic-authentication

We have an application which is protected using HTTP basic authentication.

We need to access few urls from above application in another client web application.

When ever we click on these protected urls they should come-up in new pop-up window.

We did

```
window.open("http://username:password@server:port/appcontext/otherparams");
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Internet explorer. After some google we figured that Internet Explorer doesn't support above formatted url.

Is there any alternative ways we  can make this working in all browsers?

**EDIT:**

Is there anyway we can move authentication to server end and achieve same functionality. I know we could use

```
Authenticator.setDefault
```

But not sure on how can we land back again in pop-up window after authentication. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489) which gives a lot of information on this issue.

As explained in the article, to enable username/password in url's you can edit the registry database in the following way:

> To disable the new default behavior in Windows Explorer and Internet
>   Explorer, create iexplore.exe and explorer.exe DWORD values in one of
>   the following registry keys and set their value data to 0.
>
> ```
> For all users of the program, set the value in the following registry key:
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE
>
> For the current user of the program only, set the value in the following registry key:
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE
> ```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers Please edit this post and quote relevant parts from the linked source which actually answers the concrete question straight in this post so that it becomes a fullworthy answer.

Comment: @BalusC: I have edited my question with some more information, do you think it is possible?

Comment: My comment was to uldall's answer, not to your question, Nambari. Look, it's posted on uldall's answer, not on your question.

Comment: @BalusC: yes I observed that. I know you are expert in this area, so I thought to get your view (if any answer) on my edited question.